# Adobe Flash: how to draw a grid?

Tags: adobe-flash

I'm looking for a tool\extension that lets me draw a grid in Adobe Flash.

I do **not** mean a solution via ActionScript, and drawing a few thousand cells manually with lines or rectangles, even with grid snapping, isn't an answer either. What I want is a **tool that creates a grid, mesh, table - whatever - when you select it in the toolbox and drag the mouse**.

Adobe Illustrator has this functionality built-in and it's called Rectangular Grid Tool:
http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=599358&seqNum=6

Does anyone know a way to achieve the same in Flash?

Comment: Can't you just make the grid in Illustrator then copy/paste to Flash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no existing tool or extension that accomplishes the task that you want directly in Adobe Flash from what I have found.

As Scott points out, the simplest way of accomplishing this is to create your grid within Adobe Illustrator and then copying it over to Flash. There is no need for additional plugins and the object can just be selected and transferred using Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V.

Comment: Unluckily, I do not have Illustrator installed anywhere. I found it easier to draw a couple of horizontal and vertical lines with Snap to Grid, then populate then by using `Ctrl + drag`.

Answer (score 0):

Create Grid in Illustrator.

Choose Edit > Copy

Switch to Flash

Choose Edit > Paste